# Map an array of objects using javascript, it returns an undefine values

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, parsing, object

What is the problem with my code below ? I did map based on the key that i wanted to get but i get an undefined values?. I wanted to get each random code. It did return that there are 6 total random code but it is undefined. Any problem? Thank you.

## my code \

```
let result =  me.record.job_detail.questionaires.map(a => a.random_code);
```

## the result

result

```
Array(6) [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]
```

## array of ojects (me.record.job_detail.questionaires)

> [ "{'created_at': '2019-02-07', 'department': 'sme', 'timelimit': None, 'id': 16, 'sub_title': 'this is an exam', 'title': 'exam', 'random_code': '50-49361157339'}", "{'created_at': '2019-02-07', 'department': 'TEest DEP', 'timelimit': None, 'id': 10, 'sub_title': 'this is a test', 'title': 'Hello', 'random_code': '50-612511266113'}", "{'created_at': '2019-02-07', 'department': 'SYSTECH', 'timelimit': None, 'id': 9, 'sub_title': 'Trying to test', 'title': 'Test 101', 'random_code': '50-8381637318'}", "{'created_at': '2019-02-07', 'department': 'SME', 'timelimit': None, 'id': 8, 'sub_title': 'just to test', 'title': 'Exam', 'random_code': '50-6819378387'}", "{'created_at': '2019-02-08', 'department': 'test', 'timelimit': None, 'id': 35, 'sub_title': 'test', 'title': 'test', 'random_code': '50-2143566173'}", "{'created_at': '2019-02-07', 'department': 'Test', 'timelimit': None, 'id': 13, 'sub_title': 'test', 'title': 'test', 'random_code': '50-2961010112644'}" ]

Comment: According to what you posted, you don't have an "array of objects", you have an array of *strings*.

Comment: You need to parse it using `JSON.parse()` before accessing `random_code` property

Comment: Working fine on my end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`me.record.job_detail.questionaires` is returning an array of strings. Not an array of objects. One solution would be to parse your string objects, however, at the moment they're not considered valid JSON, and so they cannot be passed using `JSON.parse()`.

Thus, you can make your string valid JSON using `.replace()`

*Using `.replace` with `JSON.parse()`*:

```js
let arr = ["{'created_at': '2019-02-07', 'department': 'sme', 'timelimit': None, 'id': 16, 'sub_title': 'this is an exam', 'title': 'exam', 'random_code': '50-49361157339'}", "{'created_at': '2019-02-07', 'department': 'TEest DEP', 'timelimit': None, 'id': 10, 'sub_title': 'this is a test', 'title': 'Hello', 'random_code': '50-612511266113'}", "{'created_at': '2019-02-07', 'department': 'SYSTECH', 'timelimit': None, 'id': 9, 'sub_title': 'Trying to test', 'title': 'Test 101', 'random_code': '50-8381637318'}", "{'created_at': '2019-02-07', 'department': 'SME', 'timelimit': None, 'id': 8, 'sub_title': 'just to test', 'title': 'Exam', 'random_code': '50-6819378387'}", "{'created_at': '2019-02-08', 'department': 'test', 'timelimit': None, 'id': 35, 'sub_title': 'test', 'title': 'test', 'random_code': '50-2143566173'}", "{'created_at': '2019-02-07', 'department': 'Test', 'timelimit': None, 'id': 13, 'sub_title': 'test', 'title': 'test', 'random_code': '50-2961010112644'}"];

let result =  arr.map(a => JSON.parse(a.replace(/'/g, '"').replace(/: (\w+)/g, ': "$1"')).random_code);
console.log(result);
```

Above, I am using `.replace` to replace all single quotes (`'`) with double quotes (so it can be parsed using `JSON.parse()`) I am also then making sure all values (like `None`) are strings, hence the second replace. Doing this will make sure your strings in your array are valid to be parsed which then allows you to access the `.random_code` property.

Comment: Good explanation, is rare he ended with that structure anyway... +1

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative (since you have strings and they are not valid JSON) could be looking on the string for the patron of your `random_code` numbers using `match()`:

```js
const input = [
  "{'created_at': '2019-02-07', 'department': 'sme', 'timelimit': 'None', 'id': 16, 'sub_title': 'this is an exam', 'title': 'exam', 'random_code': '50-49361157339'}",
  "{'created_at': '2019-02-07', 'department': 'TEest DEP', 'timelimit': 'None', 'id': 10, 'sub_title': 'this is a test', 'title': 'Hello', 'random_code': '50-612511266113'}",
  "{'created_at': '2019-02-07', 'department': 'SYSTECH', 'timelimit': 'None', 'id': 9, 'sub_title': 'Trying to test', 'title': 'Test 101', 'random_code': '50-8381637318'}",
  "{'created_at': '2019-02-07', 'department': 'SME', 'timelimit': 'None', 'id': 8, 'sub_title': 'just to test', 'title': 'Exam', 'random_code': '50-6819378387'}",
  "{'created_at': '2019-02-08', 'department': 'test', 'timelimit': 'None', 'id': 35, 'sub_title': 'test', 'title': 'test', 'random_code': '50-2143566173'}",
  "{'created_at': '2019-02-07', 'department': 'Test', 'timelimit': 'None', 'id': 13, 'sub_title': 'test', 'title': 'test', 'random_code': '50-2961010112644'}"
];

console.log(input.map(x => x.match(/\d+-\d{3,}/g)[0]));
```

However I don't recommend this unless you are really sure that there will not be data with similar format on the `strings`.